# Mobius Function of Young's Lattice

Tags: combinatorics, lattice-orders, mobius-inversion

The Wikipedia page of Young's Lattice (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young%27s_lattice) states that for $p\leq q$ the Mobius function is $\mu(p,q)=\left\{
 \begin{array}{ll}
  (-1)^{|p|-|q|}  &  \text{if the skew diagram } p/q \text{ is a disconnected union of squares}  \\
  0 &  \text{otherwise}
 \end{array}
\right.$

Question: How can I prove this?

Bonus: And what does "the skew diagram being a disconnected union of squares" actually mean for $p=(p_1,...,p_m)$ and $q=(q_1,...,q_k)$? I guess we should have something like $|m-k|\leq 1$ and $|p_i-q_i|<1$?

Comment: Hint: If a lattice $L$ is not complemented, then $\mu_L\left(0,1\right)=0$.

Comment: @darijgrinberg Could you elaborate a bit more? So if I take the lattice formed by $p,q$ and all elements between, it either has one layer of atoms only and is complemented or it is not complemented and $\mu(p,q)=0$?

Comment: Yes. The interval $\left[p,q\right]$ in Young's lattice is complemented if and only if $q/p$ (not $p/q$, by the way) is a disconnected union of squares ("disconnected" means "4-disconnected" -- i.e., squares are allowed to have vertices in common, but must not have edges in common). To see this, notice that if two squares are a common edge, then a partition containing the right (or bottom) one of these two squares will always contain the left one; thus, a partition containing only the left but not the right one cannot have a complement.

Comment: Ok this makes sense now! In the case of just one layer of atoms how does this give $(-1)^{|q|-|p|}$ though? Is there a formula for $\mu(0,1)$ when there are only atoms hiding under?

Comment: If $q / p$ is a disconnected union of squares, then the interval $\left[p,q\right]$ is isomorphic to a Boolean lattice.

Comment: Ah of course! This settles it, thank you!